# MVC Razor passing Model from View to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

My Controller which calls the View:

```
    public ActionResult Excel()
    {


        myClass arg = new myClass(string arg1, object arg2);
        return View(arg);
    }
```

My View:

```
@model myClass
@using (Html.BeginForm("createXML", "Excel", new { arg = Model }))
{ {  @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<div class="container-full" style="background-color:aliceblue">
    <h3 class="= container">Einstellungen:</h3>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="panel-group">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">nk</a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <ul class="list-group">
                                <li class="list-group-item">
                                    <form action="select.html">
                                        <label>
                                            Anzahl:
                                            <select name="decimal">
                                                <option>4</option>
                                                <option>5</option>
                                                <option>6</option>
                                                <option>7</option>
                                                <option>8</option>
                                                <option>9</option>
                                                <option>10</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </label>
                                    </form>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="panel-group">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse2">sign</a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <ul class="list-group">
                                <li class="list-group-item">
                                    <form action="select.html">
                                        <label>
                                            left:
                                            <select name="decimal">
                                                <option>4</option>
                                                <option>5</option>
                                                <option>6</option>
                                                <option>7</option>
                                                <option>8</option>
                                                <option>9</option>
                                                <option>10</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </label>
                                    </form>
                                </li>
                                <li class="list-group-item">
                                    <form action="select.html">
                                        <label>
                                            right:
                                            <select name="decimal">
                                                <option>4</option>
                                                <option>5</option>
                                                <option>6</option>
                                                <option>7</option>
                                                <option>8</option>
                                                <option>9</option>
                                                <option>10</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </label>
                                    </form>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="panel-group">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse3">Optionen</a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <form>
                                <fieldset>
                                    <ul class="list-group">
                                        <li class="list-group-item">
                                            <label>
                                                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.P5_VerkBesch)
                                                @*<input type="checkbox" name="verkBesch" value="1">*@
                                                Verk
                                            </label>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item">
                                            <label>
                                                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.P5_SpezBesch)
                                                @*<input type="checkbox" name="sFonds" value="1">*@
                                                spezbesch
                                            </label>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item">
                                            <label>

                                                <input type="checkbox" name="kgpr" value="1">
                                                kgpr
                                            </label>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item">
                                            <label>
                                                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.P5_AD)
                                                @*<input type="checkbox" name="Ad" value="1">*@
                                                ad
                                            </label>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item">
                                            <label>

                                                <input type="checkbox" name="md" value="1">
                                                md
                                            </label>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item">
                                            <label>
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="beschText" value="1">
                                                beschtxt
                                            </label>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item">
                                            <label>
                                                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.P5_Uni)
                                                @*<input type="checkbox" name="uni" value="1">*@
                                                uni
                                            </label>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </fieldset>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="panel-group">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse4">Weitere Einstellungen</a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapse4" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <ul class="list-group">
                                <li class="list-group-item">
                                    <div>

                                        <label>Anzahl Dateien pro:</label>
                                        <br />
                                        @*<small>123</small>*@
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(i => i.P5_ANZAHL, new { @type = "number", @style = "max-width: 100%" })

                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="list-group-item">
                                    <div>
                                        <label>Datum ändern:</label>
                                        <br />
                                        <p>
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.P5_DATUM, new { @id = "datepicker", @type = "text", @style = "width: 100%" })
                                            @*<input type="text" id="datepicker" style="width:100%">*@
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="list-group-item">
                                    <div>
                                        <label>Fds:</label>
                                        <br />
                                        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.P5_Fundstelle, new { @rows = "4", style = "width: 100%" })
                                        @*<textarea style="max-width:100%;" rows="4"></textarea>*@
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="list-group-item">
                                    <div>
                                        <label>Anhaltspunkte :</label>
                                        <br />
                                        @*<small>123</small>*@
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.P5_Anhaltspunkte, new { style = "width: 100%" })
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <h2>Excel</h2>
        <div>
            <form id="myForm" method="post"
                  enctype="multipart/form-data"
                  action="">
                <div>
                    <h1>File Upload</h1>
                    @if (!IsPost)
                    {
                        @FileUpload.GetHtml(
        initialNumberOfFiles: 2,
        allowMoreFilesToBeAdded: true,
        includeFormTag: true,
        addText: "Add another file",
        uploadText: "Upload")
                    }
                    <span>@message</span>
                </div>

            </form>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

}

Controller Function which should be called:

```
  public ActionResult createXML(myClass arg)
    {

//Code here...
        return View("~/Views/Excel/Excel.cshtml");

    }
```

My Problem is that "arg" is passed as null to createXML. I can't figure out why. One has to say that I am normally a WPF/WinForms Programmer.

**UPDATE**

I updated my code a bit, to make it clearer maybe.

**UPDATE 2**

I found out a part of the problem. My Object has only one constructor, where i need some paramateres. This generates somehow an error. I created a constructor without any parameter and it works, but it somehow creates a new object when I start my form and does not use the object i passed on to the view.

Comment: can you please share what html code you have inside your form. Make sure all elements are either loaded via Html helpers (e.g. @Html.TextBoxFor()) OR all elements have proper name assigned to them which matches with your class property

Comment: We need to see the code right where it says `//Code here...`

Comment: remove arg = Model and replace it with `@using (Html.BeginForm("createXML", "Excel", FormMethod.Post ))`

Comment: You cannot pass a complex object as route values like that - it would need to be `@using (Html.BeginForm("createXML", "Excel", Model ))` but it would fail if your model contains any properties which are complex objects or collection (and you will likely exceed the query string limit and throw an exception). But why in the world are you trying to send back the original unedited model - that makes no sense at all. Your form needs to include controls for properties of your model.

Comment: @KD I am on another computer right now. all elements of my form are loaded via Html helpers, as in the example you have made. And each element changes properties of the arg object.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I am changing properties of the model inside of the form. I just left this part out. My model contains compley objects.

Comment: Then remove `new { arg = Model }` (look at the html you generate for the `<form>` tag to understand why that does not work). You form need to include form controls for each property of your model.

Comment: I cant have controls for each property of my model. Some things are set in the background. Is that really an issue?

Answer (score 3):

change view like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("createXML", "Excel", FormMethod.Post))
```

and

add this above createxml

```
[HttpPost]
```

**UPDATE**

I tried your codes and worked. Here is codes

HomeController codes. You can place this methods in your ExcelController

```
public ActionResult Excel()
        {


            myClass arg = new myClass();
            arg.p = 5;
           return View(arg);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult createXML(myClass arg)
        {

            int a = arg.p;
            return View();

        }
```

Home/Excel.cshtml codes

```
@model Identity.Controllers.myClass
@{
    Layout = null;
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("createXML", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{  @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div class="container-full" style="background-color:aliceblue">
        <h3 class="= container">Einstellungen:</h3>
        <div class="container">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.p)
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: I didnt understand too

Comment: When i do this, i get an error that createXML cannot be called without an argument.

Comment: I tried all your codes, and I got worked it. Do you use your model myClass in your view? I placed @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.p) in view and it worked. p is property of myClass

Comment: When I do this, i get this error : Ausnahmedetails: System.MissingMethodException

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong overload.

You can use this overload. `BeginForm(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    Object routeValues,
    FormMethod method,
    Object htmlAttributes`)

```
@Html.BeginForm("createXML", "Excel", new { arg = Model },FormMethod.Post,null)
```

or remove the argument and use hidden field within the form:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("createXML", "Excel",FormMethod.Post))
{
    .....
  @Html.Hidden("arg", Model)
}
```

Comment: Neither of these work. The model is a complex object, and all this post back is `arg: "someAssembly.myClass"` which wont bind